# EndpointNotFoundException in separate thread hangs Main Thread

Tags: c#, wcf

I am using WCF to read data from remote computer. ReadData() method in isolated in separate thread and is surrounded by try/catch.
Still when remote host becomes unavailable and EndpointNotFoundException occurs it is noticeble that Main Thread hangs for a moment.

How is it possible? How do I fix that behaviour?

Comment: _"How is it possible? How do I fix that behaviour?"_ - Show code or it didn't happen ;)

Comment: @Fildor: I will try - I am not surrprised that you do not believe me :)